# Processing stream data with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Current I am using asyncio to process some API calls that take time to get a response. Right now, the execution flow looks like this:

```
[[task_1],[task_2]...[task_n]] => [buffer] => [asyncio event_loop]
```

The way it is currently set up is that there are always tasks coming into a buffer, and that buffer waits for the event loop to finish executing through `run_until_complete`.

This is a bottleneck as I want all the tasks to be constantly streaming into the event_loop, however, without a buffer and `run_until_complete` is not doable and if I try to ignore `run_until_complete` the machine eventually crashes, presumably due to an oom error or something on that level.

The tasks I am working on are time-sensitive, meaning the longer the tasks stay in the buffer the worse it is, I thought about creating multiple event_loops but would that even work? I feel like I am approaching this question wrong.

Tl;dr, is there a way to use something similar to `run_until_complete` but don't actually block the flow of execution, instead just chucking it into the background?

Comment: I've recently discovered gevent and it's ability to spawn tasks and execute them, seems like an asyncio alternative but I'm not sure if it will help with this problem.

Comment: It's hard to say something without seeing an example, but why not use a queue as a buffer, which will not be a bottleneck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently figured out through using gevent's greenlet units I was able to resolve the problem.

Originally, the biggest issue was not that the requests took too much CPU time, it was due to the fact that each request was taking a significant amount of IO hence the slow performance.

Through using gevent to patch the standard python utilities,  the issue was resolved:

```py
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

Some notes from the documentation is that the patching event should be **done as soon as possible and while the program is still in a single threaded state.** Also note that *only one greenlet will be run at any given time*, however since my issue was that the IO operation was halting the stream, having this approach resolved the high latency issues.